# DataType error: cannot resolve DataType of org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBufferFloat

Tags: tensorflow

Hello I'm having problems with this tensorflow function, it was written originally in flutter, if someone who did Tensorflow for a while could help me translate the original function, because my implementation sucks lol :(.

```
fun getCount(interpreter: Interpreter): Int {
    val strides = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)

    for (stride in strides) {
        val numBatches = 1

        for (batchNum in 0 until numBatches) {
            val inputShape = interpreter.getInputTensor(0).shape()
            val inputType = interpreter.getInputTensor(0).dataType()
            val outputShape = interpreter.getOutputTensor(0).shape()
            Log.d("Output tensor",outputShape.get(0).toString())


            val rawScores : Any  = emptyArray<Any>()
            val withinPeriodScores : Any = emptyArray<Any>()
            val periodScores : Any = emptyArray<Any>()

            val outputBuffer = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(,DataType.FLOAT32)

            val inShape2 = interpreter.getInputTensor(0).shape()
            val inType2 = interpreter.getInputTensor(0).dataType()

            val inputBuffer = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(inShape2, inType2)

            interpreter.run(inputBuffer, outputBuffer)

            Log.d("Output buffer", outputBuffer.toString())
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs if you pass a value of the wrong type to the run method. You can't pass a TensorBufferFloat, but need to instead pass a ByteBuffer.

Try changing the line

interpreter.run(inputBuffer, outputBuffer)

to

interpreter.run(inputBuffer.getBuffer(), outputBuffer.getBuffer())

Comment: Please help me see the difference...

Comment: Sorry, after further investigation, I don't think my previous answer was helpful. I have edited it to replace that answer with a different one that I hope is a lot more helpful.

Comment: The answer was helpful thank you Fergus